# How to read memory zone in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I'm working on a project and I have a list of functions to use.
I use the provided DLL.
I have the function's prototypes in the file "list.h".
This file is also provided to me

**list.h**

```
typedef unsigned short (__stdcall * ReadConfig)
                (void * * pDataOut, 
                 size_t * pSizeDataOut);
```

I wrote this **main.c**

```
int main (int nbArg, char** listeArg)
{

    // Initialization
    unsigned short outputFunction;
    void * pointerMemoryZone = NULL;
    size_t sizeMemoryZone = NULL;

    // Load DLL
    HMODULE dllLoadOuput= LoadLibrary("dllFile");

    // Alias Creation
    typedef unsigned short(*A_ReadConfig) (void * *, size_t *);

    // Get Pointer on Function
    A_ReadConfig ptrReadConfiguration = (A_ReadConfig)GetProcAddress(dllLoadOuput, "ReadConfig");

    // Launch of the function
    outputFunction = ptrReadConfiguration(&pointerMemoryZone, &sizeMemoryZone);

    // Display
    printf("\n\nSize Read Config : %ld\n\n", sizeMemoryZone);

    // Unload DLL
    FreeLibrary(dllLoadOuput);

    return 0;
}
```

This program works and I get the size of the memory area fine.

But my program, my variables are they correctly declared and used...?

And how can I read the data contained in the memory area...?

Below is a diagram provided in the documentation :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumming outputFunction indicates success, the pointer pointerMemoryZone should contain sizeMemoryZone bytes of data.

How you access the data depends on the format (e.g. text/json/xml string).

A sample loop to display the data in ascii and hex:

```
for(int i=0; i<sizeMemoryZone; i++) {
        char c = ((char*) pointerMemoryZone)[i];
        printf("%c{%x} ", c, c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I answer to my question. I find a solution.

I have to read datas byte by byte.

So I create a caracter pointer on "***pointerMemoryZone***" (wich contains adress of datas) by forcing the pointer type to character (because 1 byte)
And I make a loop in which I loop through the addresses one by one (along the length of the data)

Below the code for the loop

```
//...
//...
//...

// Launch of the function
outputFunction = ptrReadConfiguration(&pointerMemoryZone, &sizeMemoryZone);

// Creation of Pointer
char *pointerOnPointerMemoryZone = NULL;


// Begin Loop
for (int i = 0; i < sizeMemoryZone; i++)
{
    // Association Pointer to Adress (+0, +1, +2, etc..)
    pointerOnPointerMemoryZone = (char*)pointerMemoryZone + i;

    printf("\n%d\t\t%d\t\t%c",i, *pointerOnPointerMemoryZone, *pointerOnPointerMemoryZone);
}
// End Loop

//...
//...
//...
```